# Windows 7 Randomly Sleeps, Reason: Button or Lid?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

Though similar to other questions here, the event log yielded a different cause:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power
Date:          3/5/2015 12:00:20 PM
Event ID:      42
Task Category: (64)
Level:         Information
Keywords:      (4)
User:          N/A
Computer:      Vega
Description:
The system is entering sleep.

Sleep Reason: Button or Lid
```

This happens completely randomly a few times a day while in the middle of typing. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: **`In the middle of typing`** leads me to believe that someone tampered with your machine causing it to go to sleep whenever a key combination or sequence is pressed/typed. Do you currently have any known adversaries? It could be a virus. Does this happen if you are not typing?

Comment: What other details can you give us about the computer are you using, make, type etc. This may seem random but we had an issue with a MacBook a couple of years which would inexplicably go to sleep when the user was typing. It turned out she was wearing a magnetic "therapy" bracelet which kept tripping the magnetic lid-closed sensor. Just a thought...

Comment: This would be a Dell Inspiron 1440 (old). Had it for ~5 years but the behavior is fairly new. I'd say within the last few months or so. Sometimes its not typing, sometimes i'm just moving the mouse. Malware Antibytes doesn't report anything and I operate in a private home office (no co-workers).

Comment: Now that you mention the magnetic part, the last time it happened was when I had my cellphone resting against the keyboard. Although I couldn't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Update on this -- i can reproduce the shutdown problem by resting my phone against the keypad. That must be it!

Comment: In the last few days I started seeing the same behaviour in a Dell M6700 after years of use.  @user15333 could you describe exactly what resting phone against the keypad means? (Literally on the keys?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetic interference from my cellphone was triggering the Sleep mode. It was reproducible whenever I set my cellphone against the keypad.